# How to access a variable of an instance of a view in ContentView SwiftUI?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, instance-variables

So in ContentView, I've created a view with the following:

```
ViewName()
```

I'd like to change a variable in ContentView to the value of a variable in ViewName. I was hoping I could do something like:

```
ViewName() {
    contentViewVariable = self.variableNameInViewNameInstance
}
```

but that was just kind of a guess as to how to access the value; it didn't work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason it is needed technically it is possible to do via callback closure.

**Caution:** *the action in such callback should not lead to refresh sender view, otherwise it would be just either cycle or value lost*

Here is a demo of usage & solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
ViewName { sender in
    print("Use value: \(sender.vm.text)")
}
```

and

```
struct ViewName: View {

    @ObservedObject var vm = ViewNameViewModel()

    var callback: ((ViewName) -> Void)? = nil    // << declare

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField("Enter:", text: $vm.text)
        }.onReceive(vm.$text) { _ in
            if let callback = self.callback {
                callback(self)       // << demo of usage
            }
        }
    }
}

class ViewNameViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text: String = ""
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `@State` and `@Binding` to achieve that. You should watch these WWDC videos in 2019 to learn more about this.

- wwdc 2019 204 - introduction to swiftui
- wwdc 2019 216 - swiftui essentials
- wwdc 2019 226 - data flow through swiftui

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var variable: String

    var body: some View {
        ViewName($variable)
    }
}

struct ViewName: View {
    @Binding var variableInViewName: String

    init(variable: Binding<String>) {
        _variableInViewName = variable
    }

    doSomething() {
        // updates variableInViewName and also variable in ContentView
        self.variableInViewName = newValue
    }
}
```

Comment: So I've worked with bindings going from ContentView to another view before, but what I'm trying to do is extract a value from some view and set a variable in ContentView equal to it...In other words, setting a variable in ContentView equal to some variable that exists in ViewName

Comment: In that case you're probably looking at `PreferenceKey`. Check out this article https://swiftui-lab.com/communicating-with-the-view-tree-part-1/ to see if that helps? Otherwise you'll have to put up an example to show what you're trying to achieve.